# django rest framework invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The following RESTful API failed with an error that I have no idea what is going on there.

Here is the construct of the serializer, model and the url pattern.

**serializers.py**

```
class PatientDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PatientData
        fields = (
            'data_id',
            'data_type',
            'session_id',
            'user_id',
            'start_time',
            'time_elapsed',
            'data_file_url'
        )
        lookup_field='user_id'
```

**models.py**

```
class PatientData(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "patient_data_list"

    data_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column="data_id", primary_key=True)
    data_type = models.CharField(db_column="patient_data_type", max_length=255)
    session_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column="session_id")
    user_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column="user_id")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column="start_time")
    time_elapsed = models.IntegerField(db_column="time_elapsed")
    data_file_url = models.IntegerField(db_column="data_file_url")
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^patients/data/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', restapiviews.PatientDataListView.as_view()),
```

**restapiviews.py**

```
class PatientDataListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = PatientData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PatientDataSerializer
    lookup_field='user_id'
```

The error appears when i tried to access the localhost:8080/api/patient/data/1/ url

Comment: full stacktrace please

Comment: @Ramast, found the error. data_file_url should be a charField instead of integerfield. *facepalm*

Comment: @Max by looking at the stacktrace I'll assume :p
Glad things worked out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that your are trying to cast empty `string` or `unicode` to `int`.

I was able to run your code locally and I suspect that this happens because in your database there are empty value in fields that should be Integers. DRF IntegerField's `to_representation` method requires makes a simple casting to int, and doesn't check for empty values.
Please check your data in this manner, and if this is not the point paste your whole traceback with an error.

Comment: but it works fine for my other serializer that uses integer as look up field

Comment: The error has been found. it was an error in my model